# Php version for codeigniter 1.7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have working code of codeigniter. It is already deployed by someone else.

When I am trying to run it locally, facing lot of problems in running them.

My current php is php5 (5.3)
I think it will work well if I change php version to some older version.

What version it is ?

Because, I tried putting the applications directory into a newversion of codeigniter(2.2). I spent time changing classnames (to CI_) and changing constructors. Some parts working but some parts not working. Upgrading is not my intention, but just runing it is my intention. So, want to try downgrading version of php which might be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this](http://php.net/archive/2009.php), PHP 5.2.11 was released in September 17, 2009

according to [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html), CI 1.7.2 was released in September 11, 2009

Anyway, according with the first link, PHP 5.3.0 was released in June 30, 2009

Comment: So, you want me to try 5.2 php ?

Comment: Im just giving you some information. It seems that php 5.2 and php 5.3 should be compatible

Comment: What about the change of constructors usage in php?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_200.html Docs says - 'All native CodeIgniter classes now use the PHP 5 __construct() convention. Please update extended libraries to call parent::__construct().' - from this I thought codeigniter1.7.2 was not meant to work with php5 (bcoz my code1.7.2 uses old constructors). Either code should be wrong or php5 should be incompatible.

Comment: here you are: http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php release details and here you are: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php the change log. I think it should be compatible

Comment: I am maintaining a web application which was built with Code Igniter 1.7.2 and PHP 5.3.24. I think PHP versions *up to 5.3.29* should work fine, as they are only bug-fix versions and introduce no new features into the language.